# Bounds of the form $\left | \sum_{j=1}^n a_nb_n \right | \leq \left | \sum_{j=1}^n a_n \right | f(b)$

Tags: inequality, summation, upper-lower-bounds

Let $a=(a_1,\dots, a_n) \in \mathbb C^n$ and $b=(b_1,\dots, b_n) \in \mathbb C^n$. Suppose that $\left | \sum_{j=1}^n a_n \right | \neq 0$

I'm interested in upper bounds of the form
$$
\left | \sum_{j=1}^n a_nb_n \right | \leq \left | \sum_{j=1}^n a_n \right | f(b)
$$
for some function $f$. Can we obtain such bounds for a function $f$ that is independent (or just mildley dependent) of $a$?

Comment: What bound are you using?

Comment: @UserA wrong, try $a = b = (p,-q)$ with $p > q > 0$. Then the LHS is $p^2+q^2$ and the RHS is $p(p-q)= p^2 - pq$. Clearly RHS < LHS.